# Install mysql2 gem on macOS Sierra

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install mysql2 gem (0.4.5) on macOS Sierra (10.12.1) and getting the error. I don't have local mysql server, it's remote.

Here is error log:

```
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... no
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes 
checking for rb_intern3()... yes 
-----
Using mysql_config at /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
-----
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
-----
Don't know how to set rpath on your system, if MySQL libraries are not    in path mysql2 may not load
-----
-----
Setting libpath to /usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.9/lib
-----
creating Makefile

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log   which can be found here:
    /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.3.0-static/mysql2-0.4.4/mkmf.log

current directory: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /Users/user/.rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.4/ext/mysql2
make "DESTDIR="
compiling client.c
compiling infile.c
compiling mysql2_ext.c
compiling result.c
compiling statement.c
linking shared-object mysql2/mysql2.bundle
ld: library not found for -l-lpthread
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mysql2.bundle] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Did anyone meet similar error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Fix:**

Edit `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/bin/mysql_config`, find this line:

```
libs="$libs -l "
```

and change it to

```
libs="$libs -l mysqlclient "
```

---

**Explanation:**

> `-l-lpthread`

The linker does not understand the option `-l-lpthread`. **Two** `-l-l` linker options are jammed up against each other. It is because the library name `mysqlclient`is missing from the generated make file.

I ran into this issue when trying to build the native extensions for the `mysql2` gem on **Ruby 2.4.1** using the `mysql-connector-c` from **Home Brew**

This was on **MacOS 10.12.5**.

The generated `LIBS` variable should look something this:

`LIBS = $(LIBRUBYARG_SHARED) -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/lib -l mysqlclient   -lpthread -ldl -lobjc`

It appears the variable is expanded from the file `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/6.1.10/bin/mysql_config`

The `libs` var in the file `mysql_config` should contain:

`libs="$libs -l mysqlclient "`

**instead of**

`libs="$libs -l "`

The var `embedded_libs` may be wrong too?

The `mysql-connector-c` lib installs and build fine via `Home Brew` it just appears the file `mysql_config` is incorrect or generated incorrectly.

Not sure the cause of the issue. Possibly `Home Brew`, `mysql-connector-c`, mysql2 gem build process, user environment?

Comment: Your analysis seems correct, however after I ran `xcode-select --install` the build worked, so my hunch is that the new osx upgrade did something

Comment: Brilliant, @robdbirch !! - after two hours of scratching my head, I stumbled upon your `mysql_config` hack above.  Given the error by the OP, I believe this should be the correct answer.

Comment: I also tried the `xcode-select --install` without sucess. It was by editing that `mysql_config` file as proposed that I managed to compile mysql2 gem.

Comment: Thank you. Not only a solution which works, but also explanation why changes are made. Appreciating the help.

Answer (score 12):

The issue is that you're missing a library as the error message indicates

> ld: library not found for -l-lpthread

EDIT:
There seem to be other errors related that may be fixed with the instructions below, namely:

> ld: library not found for -lssl

My guess is that you did not install xcode yet which happens to install a few more libraries. Please make sure to install xcode through the official app-store.

It might be necessary to re-install the command-line tools again as well (even if you had xcode installed and just updated it at some point).

```
xcode-select --install
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are right, there was CLI update. I have installed it, but it didn't help

Comment: that did it for me!

Comment: I had a similar issue with `ld: library not found for -lssl` on macOS High Sierra and the above command fixed it. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the issue is that the mysql-connector-c formula is broken in Homebrew, or if the issues lies in the mysql2 gem, but you can work around the issue by installing the mysql formula.

Even if you don't need a local MySQL server for development, the version of `mysql_config` from the mysql formula correctly returns the list of libraries required to link the gem's native extension.

If you already have mysql-connector-c installed:

```
brew unlink mysql-connector-c
# OR
brew uninstall mysql-connector-c
```

Install the mysql formula:

```
brew install mysql
```